# Required true attribute not working on p:selectOneRadio when custom layout used

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using 6.1 version of PrimeFaces community. With the below code that is copied from PrimeFaces selectoneradio page, I tried to send wihtout any selection and it is not giving any error. When I upgrade the version to 7.0, it gives error, required true is working, but I have to stay on 6.1 version.

On PrimeFaces 6.1, is there any bug for this situtaion? Or is there a different usage to do my purpose on PrimeFaces 6.1?

```
<h3>Custom Layout</h3>
            <p:outputPanel id="customPanel" style="margin-bottom:10px">
                <p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio" layout="custom" required="true">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Red" itemValue="Red" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Green" itemValue="Green" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Blue" itemValue="Blue" />
                </p:selectOneRadio>

                <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">
                    <p:radioButton id="opt1" for="customRadio" itemIndex="0" required="true" />
                    <h:outputLabel for="opt1" value="Red" />
                    <p:spinner />

                    <p:radioButton id="opt2" for="customRadio" itemIndex="1" required="true"/>
                    <h:outputLabel for="opt2" value="Green" />
                    <p:inputText />

                    <p:radioButton id="opt3" for="customRadio" itemIndex="2" required="true"/>
                    <h:outputLabel for="opt3" value="Blue" />
                    <p:calendar />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: The sources are open and it is not too difficult to compare sources in github of different versions. Tried comparing 6.1 source with 7.0 source? Or 6.2?

Comment: You need to add a `<p:message for="customRadio" />` and update it on ajax submission. Then there'll be an error message rendered even with PF 6.1.